# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, web, date-range

Im currently doing a webapp in which I need to filter a chart with a date range, this range is selected with two calendars that pass the dates to two different textboxs. I have tried with two different ways: with filterparameters and with the "between @date1 and @date2" query.

The thing is i get a problem that says:

**Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.** 
This error only appears when i choose the second date range, it doesnt matter the order i choose the dates from the calendars. I've also checked my datetime conversions.

I have debbuged already and i dont see the error in my code:

```
protected void Calendar2_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDate2.Text = Calendar2.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
        Calendar2.Visible = false;
    }

    protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDate1.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
        Calendar1.Visible = false;
    }
```

---

this is my query in code and client side:

```
protected void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime date1 = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate1.Text);
    DateTime date2 = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate2.Text);

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(CONNECTION_STRING))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            try
            {
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "select Family, sum (TimeMins) as sumfield from DTCres where DateCres between @Date1 and @Date2 group by Family order by sumfield desc ";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date1", date1);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date2", date2);

                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                //SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                //if (dr.HasRows == !true)
                //{
                //    //dateLabel.Visible = true;
                //}
                //if (dr.HasRows == true)
                //{
                //    //dateLabel.Visible = false;
                //}
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception nessie)
            {
                string doc = nessie.Message;
                //dateLabel.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDS" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DTCrestronConnectionString %>" 
                    SelectCommand="select Family, sum (TimeMins) as sumfield from DTCres where DateCres between @Date1 and @Date2 group by Family order by sumfield desc"
                    FilterExpression="Family='{0}'">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:ControlParameter Name="Date1" ControlID="txtDate1" PropertyName="Text" Type="String"/>
                        <asp:ControlParameter Name="Date2" ControlID="txtDate2" PropertyName="Text" Type="String"/>
                    </SelectParameters>
                    <FilterParameters>
                        <asp:ControlParameter ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" Name="Family" ControlID="cmbChartFam1" PropertyName="Text" />
                    </FilterParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
            </td>
```

---

please, any help would be so nice, and thanks in advance

Comment: What line specifically is throwing the error?  It sounds like one of the DateTime conversions which would beg the question, what specifically is the string you are trying to convert?

Comment: You should enter this as an answer so people know you figured it out and what you found.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

Oh thanks for replying! Ive already solved it: it seems that the textbox value wans't being converted at all, so I did this: `txtDate1.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");` instead of having this: `txtDate2.Text = Calendar2.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();` I think `ToShortDateString` was creating conflict here hehe.